Samsung Galaxy A54 not detecting USB-C mobile controller until it receives charge
I bought a Gamesir X2s (mobile controller, similar to adding half an Xbox or PlayStation controller to either side of your phone) recently and have had connectivity issues with my Samsung Galaxy A54.
When I plug the Gamesir X2s into my phone, it does not detect it. However, the Gamesir X2s has a USB-C port that can be used for charging the phone through the Gamesir X2s. If I try charging my phone like this, it will detect the Gamesir X2s, and I can unplug charging and the phone will continue to detect the Gamesir X2s with no issues.
Presumably, because of capacitors inside of the Gamesir X2s, I can also plug in a charger into it when the phone is not plugged into it, and then take the charger out and plug my phone in, and they will properly connect. I can also unplug the Gamesir X2s from my phone and plug it back in and still have it detected. This seems to work up to about a minute after the Gamesir X2s has been either plugged into a charger or the phone.
Is this an issue with the Gamesir X2s, or my Samsung Galaxy A54? And is there any way I can fix this issue (such as changing settings in my phone)?
I found that a USB-C male to USB-A female adapter cable, when plugged into my phone, came up as a USB device. I thought this was odd because it is just a cable and not a USB device. However, I also have a USB-A male to USB-C female adapter, and in combination using both adapters and plugging in my Gamesir X2s into my phone, the Gamesir X2s is recognised and receives power. I can then unplug it all and quickly plug the Gamesir X2s directly into my phone and it all works.
So I guess I have found a solution, though I'd still like to find the specific root cause of this, if possible.

Not sure about this particular case and I'm not really knowledgeable about USB OTG, but I've often heard a common issue about an Android device not being able to provide enough power to the USB device so that it's not detected/working, and thus the need for an external power source.

@AndrewT.I think thats an answer.

I recently bought the Gamesir X2s for my Samsung Galaxy A54, and had no idea of this problem.
My only alternative is to plug in my relative's phone and then quickly plug into mine.
Hope someone finds a better fix.

@AndrewT is correct.  Points from the website

Android phones using Android 10 system can support it without a case.

Meaning, versions less than 10 can not.

Please be noted that X2 Type-C cannot support pass-through charging on all Type-C phones as Android OS is open source and are always amended by different developers. There are too many phones in the market and we're unable to test all the phones due to limited ability & energy. However, here is a list of mobile phones supported for your reference, https://doc.xiaoji.com/en/x2/detail/614.html

And A54 is not on that list.
Note that only later phones can charge other phones, meaning their current capacity on the USB is higher than standard.
